# WCF Service over netTCPBinding timing out for Clients in LN, working fine for Clients in US

Tags: wcf, timeout, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF Service exposed via TCPbinding running on a server in NY. I have no issues connecting to the service and getting back the results from clients connecting to this service from Americas but having issues for clients from London/Europe. I am not quite sure why this timeout issue happens but below are by Client and Server settings.

Server

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding  name="TCPBinding_IDataService"
              receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
              openTimeout="00:05:00"
              maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
              maxConnections="10"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
   <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior" name="DIT.Data.DRD.Service.PIERDataService">
    <endpoint address="DataService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBinding_IDataService"
      contract="DIT.Data.DRD.Service.IPIERDataService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9100/DRDService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
   <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="61200000" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"
                             maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
   <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default">
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="false"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
</diagnostics></system.serviceModel>
```

My client has the following settings in C# code

```
private DataServiceClient GetClient(string uri, int? timeout)
    {
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(uri),
                                                              EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost"),
                                                              new System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeaderCollection());
        NetTcpBinding svcBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        svcBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        svcBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

        svcBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.MaxConnections = 10;

        svcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
        svcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        if (timeout.HasValue)
            svcBinding.SendTimeout = svcBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, timeout.Value, 0);
        else
            svcBinding.SendTimeout = svcBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // this is default

        PIERDataServiceClient dsc = new PIERDataServiceClient(svcBinding, endpointAddress); //this is wcf client from ClientBase
        return dsc;
    }
```

Can someone having experience with WCF timeout issues shed some light on this? I've been trying to follow the gzillion posts on various forums but the understanding I gathered and implementation in the form of code and configuration is not helping much.

TIA,
Shravan

Comment: It can be some firewall or access list problem. Write test console application which will simply try to open socket to your destination address and port 9100 (or you can try to use telnet / ssh?). If it works the then problem is in WCF. If it doesn't then you have network related issue.

Comment: But the case is not all calls timeout. I call the service using multiple background worker threads (Max 5 at the same time, based on the filters user selects on the Client UI). Also this behavior is seen when data is around 40k + records for a single call. Service calls retrieving less data is fine.